# Efficient Time limit exceeded error for large number of records

Tags: apex, visualforce, community

I am quering on opportunity.

```
    List < Opportunity > getPastShowOpportunities() {

List < Opportunity > listOpportunityWithExcludeStageCriteria1 = new List < Opportunity > ();
List < Opportunity > listOpportunityWithExcludeStageCriteria2 = new List < Opportunity > ();

listOpportunityWithExcludeStageCriteria1 = [Select Id, Name, Amount, CloseDate, AccountId, StageName, Probability, Item_Type__c, TotalOpportunityQuantity, Account.Name, OwnerId, Owner.FirstName, Owner.LastName, Owner.Name, Owner.IsActive, Sales_Price__c, Product_Family__c,
Show__c, Show__r.Name, Item__c, LeadSource from Opportunity where Show__c = : listPastShow[0].Id and Item__c in : selectedProducts and StageName not in : listExcludeStages and Account.Status__c != : 'Debarred'
and TotalOpportunityQuantity != Null limit 3000];

if(listOpportunityWithExcludeStageCriteria1.size()==3000){
    listOpportunityWithExcludeStageCriteria2 =[Select Id, Name, Amount, CloseDate, AccountId, StageName, Probability, Item_Type__c, TotalOpportunityQuantity, Account.Name, OwnerId, Owner.FirstName, Owner.LastName, Owner.Name, Owner.IsActive, Sales_Price__c, Product_Family__c,
    Show__c, Show__r.Name, Item__c, LeadSource from Opportunity where Show__c = : listPastShow[0].Id and Item__c in : selectedProducts and StageName not in : listExcludeStages and Account.Status__c != : 'Debarred'
    and TotalOpportunityQuantity != Null and Id not in : listOpportunityWithExcludeStageCriteria1 limit 3000];
}

if(listOpportunityWithExcludeStageCriteria2.size()>0){
    listOpportunityWithExcludeStageCriteria1.addAll(listOpportunityWithExcludeStageCriteria2);
    listOpportunityWithExcludeStageCriteria2.clear();
}
return listOpportunityWithExcludeStageCriteria1;
}
```

I have splited my query to reduce CPU time limit. But Problem is not yet solved for CPU Time limit. 
Can any body please help me to get another solution.

Right Now my CPU time limit is 11991 out of 10000 ******* CLOSE TO LIMIT

Please help

Answer (score -1):

If your query is taking time then as per my understanding you should get 'QUERY_TIMEOUT: Your query request was running for too long' error. 
Apex CPU time limit exceeded error is thrown when your apex transactions are taking more than 10K milliseconds.

You can use below limit class methods to get CPU time for transactions:

Limits.getCpuTime() - Returns the CPU time (in milliseconds) accumulated on the Salesforce.com servers in the current transaction.
Limits.getLimitCpuTime() - Returns the total CPU time (in milliseconds) accumulated on the Salesforce.com servers in the current transaction

and re-factor your code.

Also I use below tool to analyse debug logs to find out which operations are taking more time.

https://apextimeline.herokuapp.com/#

Comment: But how time limit can be reduced. I am just querying the records modifying it for some extent and again inserting the same. While inserting also I am making batches of 2000 records and then inserting.

Comment: The point you need to analyse your debug logs may be other classes, triggers are also getting invoked !!
Downvoted , Ahhh :(